# How to fix bad encodings in a string?

Tags: python, json, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I need to correct bad encodings from a string.

This is an example of what it should be \u00c3\u00ba=ú, \u00c3\u00b1=ñ, \u00c3\u00b3=ó

This is the string:

```
x = '[{"op": "core/column-reorder", "columnNames": ["\u00ef\u00bb\u00bfN\u00c3\u00bamero de Cliente", "[Account.AccountCode?]", "CRM Origen", "Monto inicial", "[ModInitCta?]", "[DeudaRealCuenta?]", "[BillCycleName?]", "Nombre Campa\u00c3\u00b1a", "Nombre Casa de Cobro", "Fecha de Asignacion", "Deuda Gestionable", "Direcci\u00c3\u00b3n Completa", "Fecha Final", "Email", "Telefono 1", "Telefono 2", "Telefono 3", "Telefono 4", "Segmento", "[Documento?]", "[AccStsName?]", "Ciudad", "[InboxName?]", "Nombre del Cliente", "Id de Ejecucion", "Fecha de Vencimiento", "Numero Referencia de Pago", "MIN", "Plan", "Precio Subscripcion"], "description": "Reorder columns"}, {"op": "core/column-addition", "engineConfig": {"facets": [], "mode": "row-based"}, "baseColumnName": "Telefono 1", "expression": "join ([coalesce(cells['Telefono 1'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 2'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 3'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 4'].value,'')],' / ')", "onError": "keep-original", "newColumnName": "Telefonos", "columnInsertIndex": 15, "description": "Create column Telefonos at index 15 based on column Telefono 1 using expression join ([coalesce(cells['Telefono 1'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 2'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 3'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 4'].value,'')],' / ')"}, {"op": "core/column-reorder", "columnNames": ["\u00ef\u00bb\u00bfN\u00c3\u00bamero de Cliente", "[Account.AccountCode?]", "CRM Origen", "Monto inicial", "[ModInitCta?]", "[DeudaRealCuenta?]", "[BillCycleName?]", "Nombre Campa\u00c3\u00b1a", "Nombre Casa de Cobro", "Fecha de Asignacion", "Deuda Gestionable", "Direcci\u00c3\u00b3n Completa", "Fecha Final", "Email", "Telefonos", "Segmento", "[Documento?]", "[AccStsName?]", "Ciudad", "[InboxName?]", "Nombre del Cliente", "Id de Ejecucion", "Fecha de Vencimiento", "Numero Referencia de Pago", "MIN", "Plan", "Precio Subscripcion"], "description": "Reorder columns"}, {"op": "core/column-reorder", "columnNames": ["\u00ef\u00bb\u00bfN\u00c3\u00bamero de Cliente", "[Account.AccountCode?]", "CRM Origen", "Monto inicial", "[ModInitCta?]", "[DeudaRealCuenta?]", "[BillCycleName?]", "Nombre Campa\u00c3\u00b1a", "Nombre Casa de Cobro", "Fecha de Asignacion", "Deuda Gestionable", "Direcci\u00c3\u00b3n Completa", "Fecha Final", "Email", "Telefonos", "Segmento", "Ciudad", "[InboxName?]", "Nombre del Cliente", "Id de Ejecucion", "Fecha de Vencimiento", "Numero Referencia de Pago", "Plan", "Precio Subscripcion"], "description": "Reorder columns"}, {"op": "core/text-transform", "engineConfig": {"facets": [], "mode": "row-based"}, "columnName": "Monto inicial", "expression": "value.toNumber()", "onError": "keep-original", "repeat": false, "repeatCount": 10, "description": "Text transform on cells in column Monto inicial using expression value.toNumber()"}, {"op": "core/text-transform", "engineConfig": {"facets": [], "mode": "row-based"}, "columnName": "Direcci\u00c3\u00b3n Completa", "expression": "value.toTitlecase()", "onError": "keep-original", "repeat": false, "repeatCount": 10, "description": "Text transform on cells in column Direcci\u00c3\u00b3n Completa using expression value.toTitlecase()"}, {"op": "core/text-transform", "engineConfig": {"facets": [], "mode": "row-based"}, "columnName": "\u00ef\u00bb\u00bfN\u00c3\u00bamero de Cliente", "expression": "grel:value.substring(0, value.length()-2)", "onError": "keep-original", "repeat": false, "repeatCount": 10, "description": "Text transform on cells in column \u00ef\u00bb\u00bfN\u00c3\u00bamero de Cliente using expression grel:value.substring(0, value.length()-2)"}, {"op": "core/text-transform", "engineConfig": {"facets": [], "mode": "row-based"}, "columnName": "Nombre Campa\u00c3\u00b1a", "expression": "grel:value.substring(4)", "onError": "keep-original", "repeat": false, "repeatCount": 10, "description": "Text transform on cells in column Nombre Campa\u00c3\u00b1a using expression grel:value.substring(4)"}]'
```

This is the code I use to get the string:

```
import json
import ftfy

with open('get-operations.json') as j:
    data = json.load(j)
new_data = []
for dic in data['entries']:
    for key,value in dic.items():
        if key == 'operation':
            dic = {k:v for k,v in value.items()}
            new_data.append(dic)

x = json.dumps(new_data)
print(ftfy.ftfy(x))
```

I just want to extract the "operations" from this json file (get-operations.json):

```
{"entries":[{"description":"Reorder columns","operation":{"op":"core/column-reorder","columnNames":["Número de Cliente","[Account.AccountCode?]","CRM Origen","Monto inicial","[ModInitCta?]","[DeudaRealCuenta?]","[BillCycleName?]","Nombre Campaña","Nombre Casa de Cobro","Fecha de Asignacion","Deuda Gestionable","Dirección Completa","Fecha Final","Email","Telefono 1","Telefono 2","Telefono 3","Telefono 4","Segmento","[Documento?]","[AccStsName?]","Ciudad","[InboxName?]","Nombre del Cliente","Id de Ejecucion","Fecha de Vencimiento","Numero Referencia de Pago","MIN","Plan","Precio Subscripcion"],"description":"Reorder columns"}},{"description":"Create new column Telefonos based on column Telefono 1 by filling 99 rows with join ([coalesce(cells['Telefono 1'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 2'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 3'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 4'].value,'')],' / ')","operation":{"op":"core/column-addition","engineConfig":{"facets":[],"mode":"row-based"},"baseColumnName":"Telefono 1","expression":"join ([coalesce(cells['Telefono 1'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 2'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 3'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 4'].value,'')],' / ')","onError":"keep-original","newColumnName":"Telefonos","columnInsertIndex":15,"description":"Create column Telefonos at index 15 based on column Telefono 1 using expression join ([coalesce(cells['Telefono 1'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 2'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 3'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 4'].value,'')],' / ')"}},{"description":"Reorder columns","operation":{"op":"core/column-reorder","columnNames":["Número de Cliente","[Account.AccountCode?]","CRM Origen","Monto inicial","[ModInitCta?]","[DeudaRealCuenta?]","[BillCycleName?]","Nombre Campaña","Nombre Casa de Cobro","Fecha de Asignacion","Deuda Gestionable","Dirección Completa","Fecha Final","Email","Telefonos","Segmento","[Documento?]","[AccStsName?]","Ciudad","[InboxName?]","Nombre del Cliente","Id de Ejecucion","Fecha de Vencimiento","Numero Referencia de Pago","MIN","Plan","Precio Subscripcion"],"description":"Reorder columns"}},{"description":"Reorder columns","operation":{"op":"core/column-reorder","columnNames":["Número de Cliente","[Account.AccountCode?]","CRM Origen","Monto inicial","[ModInitCta?]","[DeudaRealCuenta?]","[BillCycleName?]","Nombre Campaña","Nombre Casa de Cobro","Fecha de Asignacion","Deuda Gestionable","Dirección Completa","Fecha Final","Email","Telefonos","Segmento","Ciudad","[InboxName?]","Nombre del Cliente","Id de Ejecucion","Fecha de Vencimiento","Numero Referencia de Pago","Plan","Precio Subscripcion"],"description":"Reorder columns"}},{"description":"Text transform on 99 cells in column Monto inicial: value.toNumber()","operation":{"op":"core/text-transform","engineConfig":{"facets":[],"mode":"row-based"},"columnName":"Monto inicial","expression":"value.toNumber()","onError":"keep-original","repeat":false,"repeatCount":10,"description":"Text transform on cells in column Monto inicial using expression value.toNumber()"}},{"description":"Text transform on 94 cells in column Dirección Completa: value.toTitlecase()","operation":{"op":"core/text-transform","engineConfig":{"facets":[],"mode":"row-based"},"columnName":"Dirección Completa","expression":"value.toTitlecase()","onError":"keep-original","repeat":false,"repeatCount":10,"description":"Text transform on cells in column Dirección Completa using expression value.toTitlecase()"}},{"description":"Text transform on 99 cells in column Número de Cliente: grel:value.substring(0, value.length()-2)","operation":{"op":"core/text-transform","engineConfig":{"facets":[],"mode":"row-based"},"columnName":"Número de Cliente","expression":"grel:value.substring(0, value.length()-2)","onError":"keep-original","repeat":false,"repeatCount":10,"description":"Text transform on cells in column Número de Cliente using expression grel:value.substring(0, value.length()-2)"}},{"description":"Text transform on 99 cells in column Nombre Campaña: grel:value.substring(4)","operation":{"op":"core/text-transform","engineConfig":{"facets":[],"mode":"row-based"},"columnName":"Nombre Campaña","expression":"grel:value.substring(4)","onError":"keep-original","repeat":false,"repeatCount":10,"description":"Text transform on cells in column Nombre Campaña using expression grel:value.substring(4)"}}]}
```

I've tried to use the ftfy module but it doesn't work. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Assuming the .json file is generated correctly, use `with open('get-operations.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as j:` to open the file.  Note there is no `"entries"` key in the data you provided so the `for` loop doesn't work.  Always specify the correct encoding when reading and writing files.  It would help in the future to provide the actual file and its encoding to help solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @MarkTolonen, I updated the question, I tried your suggestion encoding='utf-8-sig' however I still have problems: **[{"op": "core/column-reorder", "columnNames": ["\ufeffN\u00famero de Cliente"**...

Comment: When you use `x = json.dumps(new_data)`, use `x = json.dumps(new_data, ensure_ascii=False)`.  What you are seeing is valid JSON, but non-ASCII characters are written with escape codes.  `ensure_ascii=False` will write the actual character.  Note that `\ufeff` is actually an invisible character that is normally only at the start of a file and removed by reading the file with `utf-8-sig` encoding, but at some point the file read with that invisible character was read with `utf8` not `utf-8-sig` and it wasn't removed.  That's an error that happened when generating the file.

Comment: I get it, thank you very much for your help and explanation, it was very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right encoding when reading the file, and use `ensure_ascii=False` when writing the JSON to see human-readable non-ASCII characters.  It is still valid JSON as ASCII it is just a visual issue:

```py
import json

with open('get-operations.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as j:
    data = json.load(j)
new_data = []
for dic in data['entries']:
    for key,value in dic.items():
        if key == 'operation':
            new_data.append(value)  # original line was over complicated :)

x = json.dumps(new_data, ensure_ascii=False)
print(x)
```

Output:

```json
[{"op": "core/column-reorder", "columnNames": ["Número de Cliente", "[Account.AccountCode?]", "CRM Origen", "Monto inicial", "[ModInitCta?]", "[DeudaRealCuenta?]", "[BillCycleName?]", "Nombre Campaña", "Nombre Casa de Cobro", "Fecha de Asignacion", "Deuda Gestionable", "Dirección Completa", "Fecha Final", "Email", "Telefono 1", "Telefono 2", "Telefono 3", "Telefono 4", "Segmento", "[Documento?]", "[AccStsName?]", "Ciudad", "[InboxName?]", "Nombre del Cliente", "Id de Ejecucion", "Fecha de Vencimiento", "Numero Referencia de Pago", "MIN", "Plan", "Precio Subscripcion"], "description": "Reorder columns"}, {"op": "core/column-addition", "engineConfig": {"facets": [], "mode": "row-based"}, "baseColumnName": "Telefono 1", "expression": "join ([coalesce(cells['Telefono 1'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 2'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 3'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 4'].value,'')],' / ')", "onError": "keep-original", "newColumnName": "Telefonos", "columnInsertIndex": 15, "description": "Create column Telefonos at index 15 based on column Telefono 1 using expression join ([coalesce(cells['Telefono 1'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 2'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 3'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 4'].value,'')],' / ')"}, {"op": "core/column-reorder", "columnNames": ["Número de Cliente", "[Account.AccountCode?]", "CRM Origen", "Monto inicial", "[ModInitCta?]", "[DeudaRealCuenta?]", "[BillCycleName?]", "Nombre Campaña", "Nombre Casa de Cobro", "Fecha de Asignacion", "Deuda Gestionable", "Dirección Completa", "Fecha Final", "Email", "Telefonos", "Segmento", "[Documento?]", "[AccStsName?]", "Ciudad", "[InboxName?]", "Nombre del Cliente", "Id de Ejecucion", "Fecha de Vencimiento", "Numero Referencia de Pago", "MIN", "Plan", "Precio Subscripcion"], "description": "Reorder columns"}, {"op": "core/column-reorder", "columnNames": ["Número de Cliente", "[Account.AccountCode?]", "CRM Origen", "Monto inicial", "[ModInitCta?]", "[DeudaRealCuenta?]", "[BillCycleName?]", "Nombre Campaña", "Nombre Casa de Cobro", "Fecha de Asignacion", "Deuda Gestionable", "Dirección Completa", "Fecha Final", "Email", "Telefonos", "Segmento", "Ciudad", "[InboxName?]", "Nombre del Cliente", "Id de Ejecucion", "Fecha de Vencimiento", "Numero Referencia de Pago", "Plan", "Precio Subscripcion"], "description": "Reorder columns"}, {"op": "core/text-transform", "engineConfig": {"facets": [], "mode": "row-based"}, "columnName": "Monto inicial", "expression": "value.toNumber()", "onError": "keep-original", "repeat": false, "repeatCount": 10, "description": "Text transform on cells in column Monto inicial using expression value.toNumber()"}, {"op": "core/text-transform", "engineConfig": {"facets": [], "mode": "row-based"}, "columnName": "Dirección Completa", "expression": "value.toTitlecase()", "onError": "keep-original", "repeat": false, "repeatCount": 10, "description": "Text transform on cells in column Dirección Completa using expression value.toTitlecase()"}, {"op": "core/text-transform", "engineConfig": {"facets": [], "mode": "row-based"}, "columnName": "Número de Cliente", "expression": "grel:value.substring(0, value.length()-2)", "onError": "keep-original", "repeat": false, "repeatCount": 10, "description": "Text transform on cells in column Número de Cliente using expression grel:value.substring(0, value.length()-2)"}, {"op": "core/text-transform", "engineConfig": {"facets": [], "mode": "row-based"}, "columnName": "Nombre Campaña", "expression": "grel:value.substring(4)", "onError": "keep-original", "repeat": false, "repeatCount": 10, "description": "Text transform on cells in column Nombre Campaña using expression grel:value.substring(4)"}]
```

You can also use `indent=2` in the `json.dumps()` to get "pretty" output:

```json
[
  {
    "op": "core/column-reorder",
    "columnNames": [
      "Número de Cliente",
      "[Account.AccountCode?]",
      "CRM Origen",
      "Monto inicial",
      "[ModInitCta?]",
      "[DeudaRealCuenta?]",
      "[BillCycleName?]",
      "Nombre Campaña",
      "Nombre Casa de Cobro",
      "Fecha de Asignacion",
      "Deuda Gestionable",
      "Dirección Completa",
      "Fecha Final",
      "Email",
      "Telefono 1",
      "Telefono 2",
      "Telefono 3",
      "Telefono 4",
      "Segmento",
      "[Documento?]",
      "[AccStsName?]",
      "Ciudad",
      "[InboxName?]",
      "Nombre del Cliente",
      "Id de Ejecucion",
      "Fecha de Vencimiento",
      "Numero Referencia de Pago",
      "MIN",
      "Plan",
      "Precio Subscripcion"
    ],
    "description": "Reorder columns"
  },
  {
    "op": "core/column-addition",
    "engineConfig": {
      "facets": [],
      "mode": "row-based"
    },
    "baseColumnName": "Telefono 1",
    "expression": "join ([coalesce(cells['Telefono 1'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 2'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 3'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 4'].value,'')],' / ')",
    "onError": "keep-original",
    "newColumnName": "Telefonos",
    "columnInsertIndex": 15,
    "description": "Create column Telefonos at index 15 based on column Telefono 1 using expression join ([coalesce(cells['Telefono 1'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 2'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 3'].value,''),coalesce(cells['Telefono 4'].value,'')],' / ')"
  },
  {
    "op": "core/column-reorder",
    "columnNames": [
      "Número de Cliente",
      "[Account.AccountCode?]",
      "CRM Origen",
      "Monto inicial",
      "[ModInitCta?]",
      "[DeudaRealCuenta?]",
      "[BillCycleName?]",
      "Nombre Campaña",
      "Nombre Casa de Cobro",
      "Fecha de Asignacion",
      "Deuda Gestionable",
      "Dirección Completa",
      "Fecha Final",
      "Email",
      "Telefonos",
      "Segmento",
      "[Documento?]",
      "[AccStsName?]",
      "Ciudad",
      "[InboxName?]",
      "Nombre del Cliente",
      "Id de Ejecucion",
      "Fecha de Vencimiento",
      "Numero Referencia de Pago",
      "MIN",
      "Plan",
      "Precio Subscripcion"
    ],
    "description": "Reorder columns"
  },
  {
    "op": "core/column-reorder",
    "columnNames": [
      "Número de Cliente",
      "[Account.AccountCode?]",
      "CRM Origen",
      "Monto inicial",
      "[ModInitCta?]",
      "[DeudaRealCuenta?]",
      "[BillCycleName?]",
      "Nombre Campaña",
      "Nombre Casa de Cobro",
      "Fecha de Asignacion",
      "Deuda Gestionable",
      "Dirección Completa",
      "Fecha Final",
      "Email",
      "Telefonos",
      "Segmento",
      "Ciudad",
      "[InboxName?]",
      "Nombre del Cliente",
      "Id de Ejecucion",
      "Fecha de Vencimiento",
      "Numero Referencia de Pago",
      "Plan",
      "Precio Subscripcion"
    ],
    "description": "Reorder columns"
  },
  {
    "op": "core/text-transform",
    "engineConfig": {
      "facets": [],
      "mode": "row-based"
    },
    "columnName": "Monto inicial",
    "expression": "value.toNumber()",
    "onError": "keep-original",
    "repeat": false,
    "repeatCount": 10,
    "description": "Text transform on cells in column Monto inicial using expression value.toNumber()"
  },
  {
    "op": "core/text-transform",
    "engineConfig": {
      "facets": [],
      "mode": "row-based"
    },
    "columnName": "Dirección Completa",
    "expression": "value.toTitlecase()",
    "onError": "keep-original",
    "repeat": false,
    "repeatCount": 10,
    "description": "Text transform on cells in column Dirección Completa using expression value.toTitlecase()"
  },
  {
    "op": "core/text-transform",
    "engineConfig": {
      "facets": [],
      "mode": "row-based"
    },
    "columnName": "Número de Cliente",
    "expression": "grel:value.substring(0, value.length()-2)",
    "onError": "keep-original",
    "repeat": false,
    "repeatCount": 10,
    "description": "Text transform on cells in column Número de Cliente using expression grel:value.substring(0, value.length()-2)"
  },
  {
    "op": "core/text-transform",
    "engineConfig": {
      "facets": [],
      "mode": "row-based"
    },
    "columnName": "Nombre Campaña",
    "expression": "grel:value.substring(4)",
    "onError": "keep-original",
    "repeat": false,
    "repeatCount": 10,
    "description": "Text transform on cells in column Nombre Campaña using expression grel:value.substring(4)"
  }
]
```